# IFRAME URL Content inside a Tab doesn't Load

Tags: html, iframe, bootstrap-4

I have placed an `IFRAME` on the web page where I have set its `src` attribute to an `HTTPS` content to load. The `IFRAME` is placed inside a Bootstrap `Nav-Tab` Content; The Tab is placed inside a `Card` element.

I noted that if I load the web page, the content doesn't load;  but if I clicked on the other tab the came back all other contents in the tabs are loaded. I am intending to show a `PowerBi` report.

Unlike the earlier posting on the subject, I didn't find an exact solution. Most of them were referring to `X-Origin` but mine it works if you switch back and forth between tabs and doesn't remain blocked.

Behaviour is captured in a video: https://youtu.be/tX8utKu7tYY

My working is https://jsfiddle.net/hifni/otcek65z/13/

What I have tried so far:

1. Used the Basic IFRAME
2. Used JQuery to auto Refresh the content in an `IFRAME`
3. Used JQuery to Set the `Src` dynamically in an `IFRAME`
4. Switched between Proxy and Public Internet

Comment: Do you get any error message in the console, when opening the page the first time?

Comment: Yes, from Power BI and PowerApps saying HTTP 401 and 404 `ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE`  but on the jsfiddle there were no errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After analyzing the code from JSFiddle, the issue seems to be in the CSS. You have the following HTML part when loading the page (which represents your tabs):

```
<div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane" id="foo">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="bar">....</div>
</div>
```

And you have this CSS:

```
.tab-content>.tab-pane {
    display: none;
}
```

This means that all content is hidden. Now when you click a tab, the class `tab-pane` changes to `tab-pane active show`. And the CSS used for this looks like this:

```
.tab-content>.active {
    display: block;
}
```

The best way to solve this would be, to always automatically set the `tab-pane active show` class to the first tab element. For example:

```
<div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active show" id="foo">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="bar">....</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are a Savior!

Comment: Glad I could help :)